# how to get partial view input field value by id using jQuery in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a razor view a part of which populates the mobile number of the logged in user using partial view

```
<div class="form-group">

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.Action("ShopOwnerEditMobilePartial", "ManageShop", new { appUserId = Model.ApplicationUserId })

                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="button" value="Save Changes" onclick="updateMobile()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block pull-right" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the controller code

```
public ActionResult ShopOwnerEditMobilePartial(string appUserId)
    {
        Repository rep = new Repository();
        ViewBag.MobileNumber= rep.GetMobileNumberByAppUserId(appUserId);
        return PartialView("_ShopOwnerEditMobilePartial");
    }
```

here is the html code of the razor view

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="20" id="MobileBox"
       name="crimeRef" placeholder="Mobile Number"
       value="@(ViewBag.MobileNumber ?? String.Empty)"/>
```

Here is my code for jquery which fails to get value by using MobileBox Id

```
var CityNewValue="";
function updateCity()
{
    CityNewValue=$('#CityDDL').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("updateCity", "ManageShop")',
        method: 'post',
        data: { shopId:@Model.ShopId,NewCityID:CityNewValue},       //the data to be passed to the server
        dataType: 'json',                   // data that we are expecting back from the server
        success: function (data) {         // data variable will contain the data fetched from the server
            $('#successAlert').slideDown();
        },
        error: function (err) {

        }
    });
}
```

the problem comes when I try to get edited value of mobile number , there comes an uncaught exception against both MobileBox id and updateCity() function defined in partial view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all the code is correct , I had used `return` statement in my code , before the required work performs , that is why I was unable to reach at the desired Line of code